# Gradle copy task isn't overwriting file

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've got the following task:

preBuild.dependsOn "copyConfigFile"

```
task copyConfigFile(type: Copy) {
        from 'ConfigSources/VersionInfo.java'
        into 'src/main/java/com/company/gradleexperiments/'

        expand([changeset: "12345",
                changeset_time: "the time",
                changeset_date  : "the date"])
}
```

Its works as expected except after the file has been initially copied, if I change one of the values in the expand and build again, then the file is not being overwritten (the creation timestamp of the file in the target destination remains that last time it was built).

I did some googling and searching of past questions on this topic, however the answer I got was that the gradle copy task is by default always supposed to overwrite the file. If that is the case, then why is it not doing so for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very old bug: the copy task doesn't consider the values passed to expand as inputs, and thus considers it's up-to-date even though these values have changed.

You can vote on this issue [here](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1646).

This should be relatively easy to circumvent by adding the expanded values to the input explicitely. For example:

```
task copyConfigFile(type: Copy) {
    from 'ConfigSources/VersionInfo.java'
    into 'src/main/java/com/company/gradleexperiments/'

    def values = 
        ['changeset': '12345',
         'changeset_time': 'the time',
         'changeset_date': 'the date'];
    inputs.properties(values);
    expand(values);
}
```